# On Parallel Endomorphisms of Associated Vector Bundles

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Hey there,

Consider the following setting: given a principal $G$-fiberbundle $P\to M$ with connection form $A\in\Omega^1(P,\mathfrak{g})$ and a finite-dimensional linear representation $\rho$ of $G$ on a $\mathbb{K}$-vector space $V$. Then we have the associated $\mathbb{K}$-vectorbundle $E$ with the induced covariant derivative $\nabla^A$.

Now, if $f:V\to V$ is $G$-invariant it induces an Endomorphism $\hat{f}$ of the vectorbundle $E$ which is *parallel* with respect to $\nabla^A$. My question is: is every parallel Endomorphism of $E$ obtained this way?

Cheers,
Robert

Comment: Yep, it's a one-to-one correspondence.

Comment: Could you also explain or give a reference why this is true?

Comment: The holonomy principle says that parallel sections of $E \otimes E^*$ are in one-to-one correspondence with elements of $V \otimes V^*$ that are invariant under the holonomy group $Hol \subset G$. So if the connection is generic, $Hol = G$, and it is as I said above. In general there can be more parallel endomorphisms if $Hol$ is smaller (apologies for being careless!). You can find this in Besse, though probably with slightly less generality.